# Comparison method violates its general contract in Spark

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, comparison

I tried to sort my List[Row] data set and here is how I made for it.

```
def getDiffMinute(ts1:Timestamp, ts2:Timestamp) : Long = {
    if(ts1==null || ts2==null) 0 
    else (ts1.getTime - ts2.getTime) / 60000
}
myList.sortWith( (r1: Row, r2: Row) => 
    MYUtils.getDiffMinute( r1.getAs[Timestamp]("time"), r2.getAs[Timestamp]("time")) < 0
)
```

Since getDiffMinute function return Long type data and wortWith need bool type, there is no way to get exception.
Some data lists work so well, but others(especially big data like more than 1gb) does not work with this error.

```
Comparison method violates its general contract
```

Any Idea of this?

Comment: what's the type of your value `myList` ?

Comment: It was RDD[Row] and made list with .toList method

Comment: you can't convert an RDD[Row] into a List with .toList !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume its because your comparator getDiffMinute is not properly written.
In your case lets say B is null, then diff(A,B) = 0, diff(B,C) = 0 so diff (A,C) should be 0 too, but it can be anything if neither A and C are nulls.

more info: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)

Comment: I don't get it. I agree with diff(A, B) and diff(B, C) return 0, but diff(A, C) would return some long value.

Comment: Exactly. You have 3 values, A,B,C , your comparison says
diff(A,B) = 0 => A=B, 
diff(B,C) = 0 => B=C,  so A=B=C. That would mean diff(A,C) should be 0 too, but thats not necessarily so.

Comment: Yes, just @DanielB. said, there was 0 value somehow. you better to check your compared values more deeply.