# Java Date attribute comparator contract violation

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, comparator

I have an array list of objects which I want to sort in descending order of date (Most recent first). The class Foo has a String parameter "createdAt" which I used to define the compare to method override.

"createdAt" may be null or blank or an invalid date.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Foo foo) {
    Date created = new Date(0);
    Date otherCreated = new Date(0);

    try {
        created = Utils.getFormattedDate(createdAt);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        otherCreated  = Utils.getFormattedDate(foo.createdAt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Long.compare(otherCreated.getTime(),created.getTime());

}
```

For null checks I have defined a comparator

```
public static final Comparator fooComparator = new Comparator<Foo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
        if (o1 ==null || o1.getCreatedAt() == null) {
            return (o2 ==null || o2.getCreatedAt() == null) ? 0 : 1;
        }
        if (o2==null || o2.getCreatedAt() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

I try to use

```
ArrayList <Foo> fooList = ....
Collections.sort(fooList, fooComparator);
```

But running this code in a MapReduce Job on spark I get "Comparison method violates its general contract"

I've tried to write a lot of transitive test cases but they are passing. What am I missing?

Here is my test

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testCompare_Contract() {

    Foo t2 = new Foo();
    t2.setId(2L);
    t2.setCreatedAt(formatter.format(new Date(2018, 10, 28, 0, 0, 0).getTime()));
    t2.setText("Foo 2");

    Foo t3 = new Foo();
    t3.setId(3L);
    t3.setCreatedAt(null);
    t3.setText("Foo 3");

    Foo t4 = new Foo();
    t4.setId(4L);
    t4.setCreatedAt(formatter.format(new Date(2018, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0).getTime()));
    t4.setText("Foo 4");


    assertEquals(1, t3.compareTo(t2));
    assertEquals(-1, t2.compareTo(t3));

    assertEquals(1, t3.compareTo(t4));
    assertEquals(-1, t4.compareTo(t3));

    assertEquals(1, t2.compareTo(t4));
    assertEquals(-1, t4.compareTo(t2));

    assertEquals(0, t2.compareTo(t2));

}
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122843/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-in-spark

Comment: Yes I tried to write Test cases according to that, but they all passed.

Comment: So what happens if an exception is thrown in one of the try blocks in the compareTo method?

Comment: @sramalingam24 The date is treated as new Date(0);

Comment: I do not see the sense of your `compareTo` method instantiating objects, generating strings, and finally going out of your way to extract a `long` count-from-epoch to compare rather than just calling the built-in `Date::compareTo`. I guess your string-generation is to validate data, but a `compareTo` implementation is not the place to be doing data-validation.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).